# Adding current date and time into a bash script echo command

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that takes many hours to finish. I would like to add the current date and time to an echo command that prints to the screen every time a step completes.

So my command creates and inserts about 20 databases. some databases take several hours to insert so I would like to print the time each step finishes to the screen so you can know where in the process the restore is. Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/sh
            for DB_File in *.sql ; do
    mysqladmin create ${DB_File%%-*}
            echo ${DB_File%%-*} has been created. date +%x_%X
    mysql ${DB_File%%-*} < $DB_File

            echo $DB_File inserted into database. date +%x_%X
   done
```

Comment: Either put the date command on its own line or use `$(date +%x_%X)` to substitute the command output on the echo line.

Comment: Thanks if I use  echo $(date) it works. the $(date +%x_%X) gives an error "date: invalid date ‘=%x_%X’" but I can work with the output from just date. Thank You.

Comment: Just `date`. No need for `echo $(date)` it is pointless. And `=%x_%X` is not the same as `+%x_%X`. =)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
for DB_File in *.sql ; do
    mysqladmin create ${DB_File%%-*}
    echo ${DB_File%%-*} has been created. `date "+%F %T"`
    mysql ${DB_File%%-*} < $DB_File
    echo $DB_File inserted into database. `date "+%F %T"`
done
```

By using backquotes the *result* of date command is used. If you need another date format, just see what "date --help" has on offer.